# Genexus. error CS2001: Source file 'GxWebStd.cs' could not be found

Tags: genexus

I'm using Genexus Ev2 U5 build 80183 with .net/web environment.
After running a rebuild all I got the error:

> CS2001: Source file 'GxWebStd.cs' could not be found.

Deleting *.ari, *.00* and gxobjectcollection.cs files and doing a rebuild all, doesn't fix the issue.

Any help with this issue will be very appreciated.

Comment: english pls, so you reach more people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leonardo,

Try another rebuild all (seriously), but before doing it:

1. Delete *.ARI form the root directory of your KB
2. Delete all files from CsharpModel directory. Or better, delete the directory all below it.
3. Delete all files with the extension .SPC from your KBs subdirectory

After the rebuild all finishes there can´t be any .SPC files in your KB´s subdirectories.

I hope this fix your problem.

Comment: How? running a double rebuild-all?